# How to approach this menu design?

Tags: menus, navigation

I was given this design, and I'm struggling to find a way to implement something like this.

[image]

The 6 items on the top bar dropdown on hover, then each has a submenu in the orange box to the left. Depending on which subitem is active, the right area pulls in different images and text.

I could hard code each menu and item, and programmatically choose when to display... but I struggle to think of any plugin that would offer advanced functionality like this and allow the menu to be customized/rearranged after the fact.

Comment: You can check source code of the plugin [Max Mega Menu](https://wordpress.org/plugins/megamenu/). This plugin archives similar results.

Comment: My work arround would be to create a loop on the "sidebar" that target parent page and hide them all. With some basic javascript, display the sub menu on hover or active state of the main menu.

Comment: @Sisir I may just attempt to use that plugin and see if I can get to something which is close enough

Comment: @PatricePoliquin I am familiar with using a custom navwalker to go through and display sub menu's dynamically - but I'm not sure how I'd go about having different content under each submenu item without hardcoding them. Because subitem 1 might have an image and a paragraph of text, while subitem 2 might have a couple bullet points and a call to action button for example.

Comment: @KyleR At first glance, This plugin seems to have what you need.